# What's up with the hyphen in "orang-utan"?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, loanwords

For most of my life 'till about a couple of years ago, I had only seen the spelling *orangutan* written to describe those delightful red-headed apes from the tropical forests of Borneo.  Lately, though, I've increasingly been seeing a strange spelling in certain scientific publications I read: *orang-utan*, with a hyphen.   Is there a particular reason why this hyphen was added?  It's strange, because usually in English, words evolve to have their hyphens and diacriticals omitted, not added.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, that's the Malay spelling: The word "orangutan" comes from the Malay words "orang" (man) and "(h)utan" (forest)

Comment: I've seen [*ourang-outang*](http://www.epistemocritique.org/spip.php?article126&lang=fr) before (in older works).

Comment: @nico You should probably add that as an answer...

Comment: I don't care what anybody says, I'm saying "orangatang", because fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orangutan) about orangutan, that's the Malay spelling (although it looks like it is actually [two words](http://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orang_utan)):

> The word "orangutan" comes from the Malay words "orang" (man) and "(h)utan" (forest).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this phenomenon should have a name, maybe "hyphen decay".  A noun phrase becomes so current that starts being treated as a single word and is granted a hyphen in recognition of its new status.  If the word becomes popular enough, even the hyphen is dropped and the words fuse.

"Bell boy" becomes "bell-boy", then "bellboy".  Ditto for hundreds of other words from "type writer" to "lap top".

`Orangutan` is unusual in that the words originated in a non-Western language (albeit one that used Latin characters) and the hyphen was apparently added in the process of importing the word into English.

Comment: Not to mention electronic mail becoming e-mail and then email.

Comment: But the OP asked about a change in the other direction, where they were used to seeing orangutan as a single word, no hyphen, until recently when it seems a hyphen was introduced.

Comment: @nnnnnn -- I think that may be sample error.  The [NGrams chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=orangutan%2Cutan%2C+orang&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Corangutan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cutan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Corang%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the single word is the later arrival.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way when I was growing up in Singapore is that it's an orang utan (two words) because 'orang' means Man in Malay (one of our national languages) and 'utan' means Forest. So literally - Man of the Forest. 
The pronunciation is oh-rung u-tahn, not oh-rang-a-tan which remains really strange to hear. 
The hyphenation probably came about when someone wanted to correct it without wanting to separate the two words.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps to prevent reading it as o-ran-gu-tan instead of o-rang-u-tan.

Comment: In practice they're be the same because [ n ] becomes [ ŋ ] before [ g ].

Comment: @JonPurdy, that's exactly Danny's point, that the hyphen is there to prevent the [g] from being pronounced, i.e. to make sure it's pronounced [ɔˈræŋʊˌtæn], not [ɔˈræŋgʊˌtæn].