# Etymology of charlâtanerie

Tags: etymology, loanwords, diacritics

Can anyone provide me with the etymology and details of usage of the word *charlâtanerie* ? I came across this word while reading *The Murders in the Rue Morgue* by Edgar Allan Poe.The following passage is from from [Wikisource](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3aTales,_Edgar_Allan_Poe,_1846.djvu/136)

> There was not a particle of **charlâtanerie** about Dupin. "I will
>   explain," he said, "and that you may comprehend all clearly, we will
>   first retrace the course of your meditations, from the moment in which
>   I spoke to you until that of the rencontre with the fruiterer in
>   question. The larger links of the chain run thus—Chantilly, Orion, Dr.
>   Nichols, Epicurus, Stereotomy, the street stones, the fruiterer."

A Google search for the meaning gave me only a [single result](http://www.dictionarist.com/charlatanerie). Can anyone provide me more information so that I can add this word to [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/), the community powered dictionary?

Comment: The site you linked to has meaning and pronunciation.

Comment: @simchona Yes, it has the meaning & pronunciation.Can you provide me the etymology?

Comment: As simchona noted, *charlatanerie* is a French word. [It doesn't take a circumflex accent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/charlatanerie), though.

Comment: @F'x: the erroneous circumflex is at least in the 1846 Wiley edition on which the [linked Wikisource version](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Index:Tales,_Edgar_Allan_Poe,_1846.djvu) is based.  I wonder if it was Poe’s own error, or just that particular edition?  Unfortunately I don’t have another early edition to compare (the other versions I can find online omit the circumflex, but that could also be a later correction).

Comment: The extraneous circumflex was undoubtedly thrown in for added verisimilitude; a word isn't *really* French unless it has an accent on a vowel or a cédille on a c. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Charlatanerie* is not an English word, and is a borrowing from French. According to the French version of [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/charlatanerie), it is the same as the English word *charlatanry*. [*Charlatanry*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Charlatanry) is the act of being a *charlatan*, which is:

> A person who makes elaborate, fraudulent, and often voluble claims to skill or knowledge; a quack or fraud.

I would not add *charlatanerie* to the Wiktionary page, as it is not really an English word. You could, however, note that it is the French translation of *charlatanry*. There is already a Wiktionary [entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/charlatanry) for *charlatanry* available.

[EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=charlatan) notes that the origins of *charlatan* are:

> 1610s, from Fr. charlatan (16c.), from It. ciarlatano "a quack," from ciarlare "to prate, babble," from ciarla "chat, prattle," perhaps imitative of ducks' quacking. Related: Charlatanism.

Comment: +1, Since the novel is supposed to take place in Paris, Edgar Poe seem to have privileged French spellings in some occasions.  See for instance [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21466/whats-up-with-the-hyphen-in-orang-utan/21489#21489).  Browsing through the [text](http://poestories.com/text.php?file=murders) one can see multiple examples of this.